# How to debug React Native (Core) code in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, react-native

I want to debug native classes connected with Network layer in my application when `fetch` is being executed. I've tried to open the project (from root point) in Android Studio but the IDE didn't see something connected with Android part. What do I have to do?

I am not an Android developer.

Answer (score 1):

With Android studio, you have to open the android folder in the root directory. [Look at this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swmc2.png)

Edit
[Look at this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1LFa.png)

Edit 2 This may be the core ? [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejztA.png)

Comment: You didn't understand I want to debug core classes of RN

Comment: How did you open the project in Android Studio? If I open my project from root directory (RN), Android Studio doesn't see my project! And I can't attach to the process.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out a bit!

Comment: Edit 2 is correct, this should be accepted (and maybe cleaned up a bit) :) Nice!